# How to start Jupyter Notebook that it ignores PYTHONPATH environment variable

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook, pythonpath

At the moment I start the [Jupyter Noteboo](https://jupyter.org/)k with the following command:

```
jupyter notebook --notebook-dir="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Jupyter"
```

But how can I start a Jupyter Notebook which ignores the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

I know I can do it for Python using the `-E` [option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-e):

> Ignore all PYTHON* environment variables, e.g. PYTHONPATH and
>   PYTHONHOME, that might be set.

My system configuration:

- Windows 10 64 bit Enterprise 1709
- Python 3.6.6
- jupyter-core 4.4.0
- notebook 5.7.4

The command `jupyter notebook --help-all` shows me all command line options, but I can't find one to ignore `PYTHONPATH`.